# Finding matches from one large file in another?

Tags: bash, shell, perl

I have two email lists.  One is a newline delimited file of just email addresses containing 100k lines and the second file contains email,date,ipaddress newline.  It has 4M lines, and contains duplicates which I am not concerned with.

grep -f fileA.txt fileB.txt works when fileA.txt is a test file of 100 or 1000 lines but 100k it is isn't getting anywhere.

I'm open to perl as well :)

Answer (score 1):

When faced with this kind of thing and I don't/can't store all of one file in an array, as suggested by Eric, I resort to a slightly unconventional approach. Each file is exported to a separate table in a database (I like Perl for this part) and the desired results are obtained via SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming Linux with this. I would try creating a [ramdisk](https://superuser.com/questions/175861/ramdisk-ubuntu-10-04) and putting both files in it. That may be the fastest thing to try. Put this in fstab and then do a mount /mnt for a really quick way of setting it up:

```
ramdisk /mnt tmpfs mode=1777,size=1G
```

Comment: I don't think speed is the issue. The OP seems to be asking how to do this and with only 100k lines that should occur in the blink of an eye.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to speed it up a bit by using the `-F` option so it's searching for fixed strings.

```
grep -Ff fileA.txt fileB.txt
```

Did you time your tests? What does extrapolating that time to the larger files tell you?

Comment: A test I just performed showed a considerable difference when using `-F`. `time grep -Fqsf 30000-lines 900000-lines` took about 1.2% of the time of `time grep -qsf 10000-lines 900000-lines`! Note that's with *three times as many lines* in the pattern file!

Answer (score 0):

Sort and then diff them? That ought to work.

Comment: The files are different sizes, diff wont work I think

Comment: Diff will work on files of different sizes. I do like John's answer of using SQL, that's something that it's very good at.

Answer (score 0):

in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my ($emailfile, $file2);

if ( open ( $emailfile, '/path/file') )
{
  my @emails = split(/\n/, $emailfile);

  if ( open ( $file1, '/path/file') )
  {
    foreach my $email ( @emails )
    {
      while ( <$file2> )
      {
        if ( $_ =~ /$email/)
          print $_;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Won't that try to put all file in the memory, for each one of the loops?

Comment: true, sorry, you can also place the foreach loop inside the while loop to only iterate the larger file once. I just went a little too fast for myself :/